# Has anyone gotten Kimono meta APIs to combine results from multiple APIs?

Tags: api, web-scraping, kimono

The documentation describes a meta collection as a combination of 2 (or more) different APIs...

> By default, a meta API endpoint returns all data from all of its
>   sub-APIs, organized by collection.

But, what I find is that it does not do this. It grabs partial data from *some* sub-APIs and fails silently, without logging an error.

**API #1 Result**

```
COLLECTION2
ROW LIST.HREF                                               LIST.TEXT     INDEX URL
1   http:/​/​www.amazon.com/​Org...pollux+​organix+​canned+​dog Canned Dog Food 3   http:/​/​www.austinpetsalive.org/​donate/​wish-​list/​
2   http:/​/​www.amazon.com/​Pre...s-​Large/​lm/​R34ISSXSRJPA71 Premier Brand Martingale collars (Pink, Silver, Blue, Red, and Orange) sizes XL or L    4   http:/​/​www.austinpetsalive.org/​donate/​wish-​list/​
3   http:/​/​www.amazon.com/​Pre...ords=​medium+​gentle+​leader Medium & Large Gentle Leaders   5   http:/​/​www.austinpetsalive.org/​donate/​wish-​list/​
```

**API #2 Result**

```
COLLECTION2
ROW LIST.HREF LIST.TEXT    INDEX    URL
1             Dry kitten and adult dog food (we ask that the first ingredient listed on the bag be meat). Some Brands we love include: Purina One, Pro-Plan, Wellness, Evolve, Blue Buffalo, and Kirklands  9   http:/​/​pawsshelter.org/​donate/​wishlist/​
2             Cat Litter    10  http:/​/​pawsshelter.org/​donate/​wishlist/​
3             Kongs, Balls, Durable Toys, Puzzle Toys   11  http:/​/​pawsshelter.org/​donate/​wishlist/​
```

**Meta API Result Collection 2 -- it's the entire data set from API #2 and none from API #1**

```
COLLECTION2
ROW LIST.HREF   LIST.TEXT   INDEX   URL API
1       Dry kitten and adult dog food (we ask that the first ingredient listed on the bag be meat). Some Brands we love include: Purina One, Pro-Plan, Wellness, Evolve, Blue Buffalo, and Kirklands    132 http:/​/​pawsshelter.org/​donate/​wishlist/​    PAWS Shelter and Humane Society
2       Cat Litter  133 http:/​/​pawsshelter.org/​donate/​wishlist/​    PAWS Shelter and Humane Society
3       Kongs, Balls, Durable Toys, Puzzle Toys 134 http:/​/​pawsshelter.org/​donate/​wishlist/​    PAWS Shelter and Humane Society
```

The data structure is verbatim the same. Why don't they combine under meta API?

---

**Testing**

- A meta API combination worked with 2 APIs, each with one collection.
- When there is more than one collection defined, certain combinations of APIS combined partially. Each collection filled with the contents of one or the other API, but never both.
- The 3 APIs I need to combine result in one site's results in all of the collections, and nothing from the other two in any collection, and no error logged.

The flaky results seem tied to the collections. But I've moved on to a klugey temp fix, which is to call each API separately and combine the JSON results in my app. 3 API calls instead of one. Might be looking for another tool, soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Now it works**

Since I posted this question in October, KimonoLabs has updated their app and I am now having consistent success with creating and using a Meta API for the set of single APIs I posted above.

That's the positive.

The catch is that you **cannot use the URL parameters in a meta API**, so if you'd written post-process modify results functions, they will not be executed, even if you use `kimmodify=1`.